# How to create a point behind another point given an angle?

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry, vector-spaces, coordinate-systems, angle

I have a point **A** and a radian angle value **R** (image below describes this heading system) that represents a heading from point **A**.

[image: https://image.ibb.co/eps56d/radian.jpg]

How do I create a point **B** that is a small, fixed distance (like 1.0 units) "behind" or "opposite" point **A**'s heading? The image below diagrams my available information and my desired product:

[image: https://image.ibb.co/fzAgey/problem.jpg]

Comment: If the center of the circle is the origin. Then $B = \alpha A$ for an appropriate value of $\alpha$.

Comment: Can you be explicit with your formula? I am unfamiliar with mathematical symbols and/or their meanings. As for the center point of the circle, I do believe A can be defined as the center. My only requirement of B is that is in the exact opposite side of A's heading